# how to get the original start_url in scrapy (before redirect)

Tags: python, redirect, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to crawl some pages. I fetch the start_urls from an excel sheet and I need to save the url in the item.

```
class abc_Spider(BaseSpider):
   name = 'abc'
   allowed_domains = ['abc.com']         
   wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path + '/somefile.xlsx')
   wb.sheet_names()
   sh = wb.sheet_by_name(u'Sheet1')
   first_column = sh.col_values(15)
   start_urls = first_column
   handle_httpstatus_list = [404]

   def parse(self, response):
      item = abcspiderItem()
      item['url'] = response.url
```

The problem is that the url gets redirected to some other url (and thus gives something else in the response url). How do I get the original url that I got from the excel?

Comment: Have you tried `response.request.url`?

Comment: @alecxe: yes, tried that too, got me the redirected url again, the same url I got from response.url

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can find what you need in `response.request.meta['redirect_urls']`.

Quote from [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:reqmeta-redirect_urls):

> The urls which the request goes through (while being redirected) can
>   be found in the redirect_urls Request.meta key.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @alecxe do you have any idea why `response.request.meta['redirect_urls']` might work in the scrapy shell but throw a `exceptions.KeyError: 'redirect_urls'` when used in a script? I know the redirect occurs from looking at `response.url`

Comment: @AdO sounds like use-case specific, could you create a new separate question and provide all the details, throw me a link here, I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @alecxe thanks, have posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618597/unable-to-access-request-response-metaredirect-urls-from-scrapy-script

Answer (score 2):

This gave me the original 'referer URL', i.e. which of my start_urls led to the URL corresponding to this request object being scraped:

```
req = response.request
req_headers = req.__dict__['headers']
referer_url = req_headers['Referer'].decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for the answer-

For `Scrapy 2.6+` version

use -
`response.request.headers.get('Referer', None).decode("utf-8")`

It will give you the original URL (originally in byte string, hence string conversion)

for more - [Scrapy request response](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)