# Scrapy redirect_urls exception.KeyError

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy & Python, recently launched my first spider. There is a feature that seems to have worked before though now it only works for some of the websites I am trying to scrap.

The code line is:

```
item['url_direct'] = response.request.meta['redirect_urls']
```

and the error I get is:

```
exceptions.KeyError: 'redirect_urls'
```

I have been struggling with this for a while so any clue or hopefully a more detailed answer will be very much appreciated. (Didn't find a similar question here or on the web).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, `response.request.meta['redirect_urls']` is set by the [RedirectMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect) to any URLs that the request may have gone through while being redirected.

For requests that haven't been redirected, that code will fail with a `KeyError`.

Since `response.request.meta` is just a dict, you can use:

```
item['url_direct'] = response.request.meta.get('redirect_urls')
```

Or you can check it before setting:

```
if 'redirect_urls' in response.request.meta:
    item['url_direct'] = response.request.meta['redirect_urls']
```

#### See also:

- [RedirectMiddleware docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect)
- [how to get the original start_url in scrapy (before redirect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843088/how-to-get-the-original-start-url-in-scrapy-before-redirect) (related question)

Comment: I couldn't vote the comment, but it helped me. Thanks.