# Unable to access request.response.meta['redirect_urls'] from Scrapy script

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am unable to access `request.response.meta['redirect_urls']` from my Scrapy script, but have no problem accessing this information for the same webpage in the Scrapy shell. When I print the keys of `request.response.meta` I only see `download_timeout, depth, download_latency, download_slot`

I am wondering if this is to do with one of the settings I have modified in my Scrapy script which contains the following:

```
settings.set('DEPTH_LIMIT', 4)
settings.set('DOWNLOAD_DELAY', 1)
settings.set('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)')
settings.set('SPLASH_URL', 'http://192.168.59.103:8050')
settings.set('DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES', {'scrapyjs.SplashMiddleware': 725})
settings.set('DUPEFILTER_CLASS', 'scrapyjs.SplashAwareDupeFilter')
settings.set('HTTPCACHE_STORAGE', 'scrapyjs.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage')
```

I know redirection is also handled by middlewares so is this an issue because I am using SplashMiddleware and is it possible to use both? I know the redirection is happening from looking at `response.url`

Many thanks

Comment: Can you see the redirection in the log? DEBUG level

Comment: @StevenAlmeroth thanks for your suggestion! When I used the DEBUG rather than ERROR level it became clear that the script was being passed an incorrect start_url and request.response.meta['redirect_urls'] is still accessible when using the SplashMiddleware :)